# Get the <T> type in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

For example in my case I need to reuse the type of a component in React (`React.FC`) but I want it with optionals props by using `Partial<T>`.

Is there a way to "get" the Generic `<T>` from that component type (`type TypeTargetComponent = React.FC<T>`) ? I would like to do something like : `React.FC<Partial<XXXX<typeof TargetComponent>>>` where `XXXX`is the "method" to get what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
type ExtractPropsType<T> = T extends React.FC<infer Type> ? Type : never;
```

This should work if you type `typeof TargetComponent`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the infer keyword.

Something like this should work:

Updated the answer to include example and fixed the type inferrence issue.

```
type FC<T> = { data: T }

type InferredValueOf<Comp extends FC<any>> = Comp extends FC<infer T> ? T : never

type Derived<TargetComponent> = TargetComponent extends FC<any> ? FC<Partial<InferredValueOf<TargetComponent>>> : never

type TestType = Derived<FC<{ testValue: "value" }>>

const test: TestType = {
    data: {
        // testValue is optional now
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently there is something wrong with ```TargetComponent```, it ```does not satisfy the constraint 'FC<any>'```

Comment: Yea... this fixes that. Might make more sense to combine them
`
type Derived<TargetComponent> = TargetComponent extends FC<any> ? FC<Partial<InferredValueOf<TargetComponent>>> : never
`